# How to add popover or tooltip on event hover in fullCalendar in react?

Tags: popup, fullcalendar, tooltip, react-bootstrap

I have implemented Full Calendar API in my application.I am using react-bootstrap and want to show up popover or tooltip on event hover.I am not getting of how to implement this in full calendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo shows how to render tooltip on event hover in fullCalendar using js. Till now what I have tried.

```
<FullCalendar
          ref={calendarRef}
          plugins={[
            interactionPlugin,
            resourceTimeGridPlugin,
            dayGridPlugin,
            scrollGridPlugin,
          ]}
          schedulerLicenseKey="CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives"
          headerToolbar={false}
          resources={filteredResources}
          events={appointments}
          initialView="resourceTimeGridDay"
          slotDuration={{ minute: "30" }}
          slotMinTime={{ hour: "08" }}
          slotMaxTime={{ hour: "21" }}
          slotLabelInterval={{ hour: "01" }}
          editable={false}
          selectable={true}
          dayMaxEvents={true}
          dateClick={handleDateClick}
          eventClick={handleEventClick}
          allDaySlot={false}
          dayMinWidth={150}
          height={"auto"}
          stickyFooterScrollbar={true}
          eventDidMount={(info) => {
            console.log(info);
            return (
              <OverlayTrigger
                key="top"
                placement="bottom"
                trigger="hover"
                overlay={
                  <Popover id="popover-basic">
                    <Popover.Header as="h3">{info.event.title}</Popover.Header>
                    <Popover.Body>
                      And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's
                      very engaging. right?
                    </Popover.Body>
                  </Popover>
                }
              >
                {document.getElementsByClassName("fc-event-main")[0]}
              </OverlayTrigger>
            );
          }}
        />
```

Below is the screenshot of the calendar created.
[image]

Comment: Please don't repost your questions, so they get pushed...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method `eventMouseEnter` as a `prop` In my case I just displayed a simple alert but you can implement your tooltip library note that I have used FullCalender version 6

```
  eventMouseEnter: function (mouseEnterInfo) {
    alert("hovered over " + mouseEnterInfo.event.title);
},
```